# do all page load rules execute on each page or only the rule related to that page

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have 20 page load rules  . 
My question is do all page load rules execute on each page or only the rule related to that page .
Reason why I am asking is 
when i have condition  path contains and i hardcode the path or URL , in DTM debugger only the page load rule fires shows ,
whereas when i  create a data element where i get value from page title and add condition to rule  data element value =  title ,
there it shows condition not met for all the other pages .

If i understand it correct then when url strings is defined as static it is not evaluating all page load rules ,
WIll evaluating all page load rules based  on data element make the page slow or all rules evaluate anyways .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All page load rules have their conditions evaluated on every page load. However, not all of them actually show a console log (a `_satellite.notify()` call) of it. because..reasons? Honestly, I don't know why it's not consistent but at one point I did dig into the core DTM library and confirm that it doesn't always make a `_satellite.notify()` call, based on stuff like you pointed out.  And yeah, it's kind of annoying.

> WIll evaluating all page load rules based on data element make the page slow or all rules evaluate anyways .

As mentioned, all of the page load rules will have their conditions evaluated on every page. This will impact page performance, sure. But the contents of a given page load won't actually be executed unless all of the conditions for the rule evaluates `true`.

And, whether or not the contents in a given rule are even (pre)loaded depend on how you setup the rule. Page load rules set to evaluate synchronously (page top/bottom) or have tags in them set to output synchronously will have their contents synchronously loaded, regardless of whether or not all of the conditions actually evaluate true (and if they *are* true, then it will be executed).

Comment: Also be aware that not all conditions are created equal. Certain condition types will execute as an "and/or" (IE: condition 1 or condition 2) vs an "and/and" fashion (condition 1 and condition 2). Unfortunately, there isn't always a hard and fast rule (other than testing) to determine how 2 conditions work together.

Comment: @MarkStringham can you please provide an "and/or" example? The doc says [all conditions must evaluate true](https://helpx.adobe.com/dtm/kb/do-multiple-conditions-in-a-rule-evalutes-as-AND-OR-statements.html). I know sometimes the doc is wrong but to date I have personally never seen it work otherwise.

Comment: URL path match = "and/or"

Comment: @MarkStringham it looks like you are right. I also found multiple subdomain conditions act as an OR condition.  Well that's good to know, thanks!

Comment: Same goes for data elements. Conditions like URL path = "X" AND data elementX = "Y" will fail. In those cases, I recommend using the custom condition field instead.